# Mi clase de python no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x

ando aprendiendo POO en python e hice el siguiente código, pero por alguna razón no imprime nada. No sé que ando haciendo mal.

```
class Lavadora:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _llenar_tanque_agua(self, temperatura):
        print(f'llenando el tanque de agua {temperatura}')

    def _anadir_jabon(self):
        print('anadiendo jabon')
    
    def _lavar(self):
        print('lavando la ropa')

    def _centrifugar(self):
        print('centrifugar')

    def lavar(self, temperatura='caliente'):
        self._llenar_tanque_agua(temperatura)
        self._anadir_jabon()
        self._lavar()
        self._centrifugar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lavadora = Lavadora()
    lavadora.lavar
```

Cualquier sugerencia les agradezco mucho :)
Saludos a todos

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar una función debes usar los parentesis, de lo contrario estas solicitando información sobre la funcion, ejemplo:

**Forma erronea**:

Codigo

```
lavadora.lavar
```

Salida

```
<bound method Lavadora.lavar of <__main__.Lavadora object at 0x7f334a141ee0>>
```

**Forma correcta:**

Código:

```
lavadora.lavar()
```

Salida:

```
llenando el tanque de agua caliente
anadiendo jabon
lavando la ropa
centrifugar
```

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente es lo que te está diciendo @Nicolas Acosta . Te dejo una explicación más detallada

### Métodos.

Siempre que creas funciones dentro de una clase (son llamadas métodos), tienes que llamarlas igual que llamas a cualquier función usando los paréntesis, ya que si no lo que haces es devolver la propia función con la información y su dirección de memoria.

Es exactamente lo que estás haciendo dentro del método `lavar()` llamas a las funciones `_llenar_tanque_agua(temperatura), _anadir_jabon() ...` con los paréntesis ya que si no te estarías trayendo información sobre la propia función, en vez de ejecutarla que es lo que quieres.

### Atributos

Los atributos son las variables que pertenecen a la propia clase, en este ejemplo tú no has definido ninguno, pero podrías hacerlo (aunque para este tipo de objeto no es la forma más correcta, puedes hacerlo así:

```
class Lavadora:
    def __init__(self, temperatura):
        self.temperatura = temperatura

    def _llenar_tanque_agua(self):
        print(f'llenando el tanque de agua {self.temperatura}')

    def _anadir_jabon(self):
        print('anadiendo jabon')
    
    def _lavar(self):
        print('lavando la ropa')

    def _centrifugar(self):
        print('centrifugar')

    def lavar(self):    
        self._llenar_tanque_agua()
        self._anadir_jabon()
        self._lavar()
        self._centrifugar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Construimos el objeto indicándole que la temperatura será caliente
    lavadora = Lavadora('caliente')
    lavadora.lavar()
```

## Poner métodos como atributos

**Disclaimer:** Esto es simplemente para que lo tengas en cuenta, por si lo ves, que lo entiendas, pero si estás empezando, no te fijes demasiado.

En Python dentro de las clases se pueden ponen poner funciones como atributos, en vez de como métodos. Es decir que la función sea una **propiedad** de la propia clase. Esto te permite llamar a la función sin los paréntesis como si fuera un atributo. Se hace con el decorador `@property` que tiene Python:

```
class Lavadora:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _llenar_tanque_agua(self, temperatura):
        print(f'llenando el tanque de agua {temperatura}')

    def _anadir_jabon(self):
        print('anadiendo jabon')
    
    def _lavar(self):
        print('lavando la ropa')

    def _centrifugar(self):
        print('centrifugar')

    @property
    def lavar(self):    
        self._llenar_tanque_agua('caliente')
        self._anadir_jabon()
        self._lavar()
        self._centrifugar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lavadora = Lavadora()
    lavadora.lavar
```

En este caso, como hemos convertido la función en un atributo, podemos llamarla sin usar paréntesis.

**Disclaimer 2:** como indiqué arriba, esto es bastante avanzado si no tienes conocimientos de clases en Python y **no es la forma indicada de crear las funciones que están dentro de una clase**, salvo que sepas muy bien lo que estás haciendo. Sus casos de uso son limitados, como por ejemplo en **Descriptors**